# Validar select en formulario de registro

Tags: php, mysql, html5, bootstrap, select

Estoy haciendo un formulario de relleno de registro donde todo iba bien a excepcion del select, el codigo es el siguiente:

**Base de datos:**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
tipo_de_usuario VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
fecha_registro DATETIME NOT NULL,
activo TINYINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

**Constructor:**

```
class ValidadorRegistro {
private $aviso_inicio;
private $aviso_cierre;

private $tipo_de_usuario;
private $nombre;
private $email;
private $clave;

private $error_tipo_de_usuario;
private $error_nombre;
private $error_email;
private $error_clave1;
private $error_clave2;

public function __construct($tipo_de_usuario, $nombre, $email, $clave1, $clave2, $conexion) {
    $this->aviso_inicio="<br><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
    $this->aviso_cierre="</div>";


    $this->tipo_de_usuario = "";
    $this->nombre = "";
    $this->email = "";
    $this->clave ="";

    $this->error_tipo_de_usuario = $this->validar_tipo_de_usuario($tipo_de_usuario);
    $this->error_nombre = $this->validar_nombre($conexion, $nombre);
    $this->error_email = $this->validar_email($conexion, $email);
    $this->error_clave1 = $this->validar_clave1($clave1);
    $this->error_clave2 = $this->validar_clave2($clave1, $clave2);

    if($this->error_clave1 === "" && $this->error_clave2 === ""){
        $this-> clave = $clave1;
    }
}
```

**Validador select:**

```
private function validar_tipo_de_usuario($tipo_de_usuario) {
if ($this->variable_iniciada($tipo_de_usuario)) {
    return "Debes seleccionar un tipo de usuario.";
} else if ($tipo_de_usuario == "Individuo (Persona Natural)"){
    $this-> tipo_de_usuario = $tipo_de_usuario;
} else if ($tipo_de_usuario == "Empresa o negocio (Persona Juridica)"){
    $this-> tipo_de_usuario = $tipo_de_usuario;
}
```

**Mostrar error tipo de usuario (select):**

```
$this->error_tipo_de_usuario = $this->validar_tipo_de_usuario($tipo_de_usuario);

public function mostrar_tipo_de_usuario(){
    if($this->tipo_de_usuario!==""){
        echo 'value="'. $this -> tipo_de_usuario . '"';
    }
}

public function obtener_error_tipo_de_usuario(){
    return $this-> error_tipo_de_usuario;
}

$this->aviso_inicio="<br><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
$this->aviso_cierre="</div>";

public function mostrar_error_tipo_de_usuario(){
    if($this->error_tipo_de_usuario!==""){
        echo $this->aviso_inicio . $this -> error_tipo_de_usuario . $this->aviso_cierre;
    }
}
```

**Registro valido: Inserta en la base de datos solo si no hay errores en ningun campo a llenar (por si acaso este fragmento de codigo)**

```
public function registro_valido(){
    if($this-> error_tipo_de_usuario === "" && $this-> error_nombre === "" && $this-> error_email === "" && $this-> error_clave1 === "" && $this-> error_clave2 === ""){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Select Vacio:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo de Usuario: </label>
    <select name="tipo_de_usuario" class="form-control">
        <option>Seleccione... </option>
        <option value="Individuo (Persona Natural)">Individuo (Persona Natural)</option>
        <option value="Empresa o negocio (Persona Juridica)">Empresa o negocio (Persona Juridica)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Select Validado (Lo que debe aparecer cuando uno selecciona una de las opciones y no ingreso otro dato o lo ingresó mal):**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipo de Usuario: </label>
    <select name="tipo_de_usuario" class="form-control">
        <option>Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="Individuo (Persona Natural)">Individuo (Persona Natural)</option>
        <option value="Empresa o negocio (Persona Juridica)">Empresa o negocio (Persona Juridica)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Ingresar usuarios a la base de datos:**

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
Conexion :: abrir_conexion();

$validador = new ValidadorRegistro($_POST['tipo_de_usuario'], $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['clave1'], $_POST['clave2'], Conexion :: obtener_conexion());
if($validador->registro_valido()){
    $usuario = new Usuario('', $validador-> obtener_tipo_de_usuario(), $validador-> obtener_nombre(), $validador-> obtener_email(), password_hash($validador-> obtener_clave(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT), '', '');
    $usuario_insertado = RepositorioUsuario :: insertar_usuario(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $usuario);

    if($usuario_insertado){
        Redireccion :: redirigir(RUTA_REGISTRO_CORRECTO. '/' . $usuario -> obtener_nombre());
    }
}
Conexion :: cerrar_conexion();
}
```

El problema es que cada vez que selecciono alguna de las opciones del select aun ingresando todo lo demas correctamente (nombre, correo, clave1 y clave2 iguales) y pulsando el boton que envia formularios (esta bien programado) no se envia nada a la base de datos, y tampoco almacena la opcion seleccionada en caso de ingresar otro de los datos mal, ¿En que parte del codigo me estoy equivocando y como se escribe el codigo a corregir? Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Tu Select Vacio y Select Valido son iguales.

Comment: @alanfcm como puedo escribir el codigo en el select valido?

Comment: Editando tu pregunta.  Talvez sea bueno que incluyas el codigo de como guardas a la base de datos.

Comment: Las funciones de validacion las llamas en el constructor de `ValidarRegistro`?  Deberias de incluir la consulta `SQL`

Comment: @alanfcm listoo